# Model manager method works on dev server, but does not on production

Tags: python, django, model, production

I have this model manager:

```
class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def search(self, text):
        import logging
        logging.info(222222222222, text)
        vector = pg_search.SearchVector('brand__brand_name', weight='A') +\
                pg_search.SearchVector('title', weight='A')+\
                pg_search.SearchVector('description', weight='C')
        query = pg_search.SearchQuery(text)
        rank = pg_search.SearchRank(vector, query)
        logging.info(111111, text)
        return self.get_queryset().annotate(rank=rank).filter(search_vector=query).annotate(document=vector).order_by('-rank')
```

It is used in my model:

```
class Product(TimeStampedModel):
    '''some fields'''
    objects = ProductManager()
```

Next in my **views.py** I have:

```
logging.info(search)
products_list = Product.objects.search(search).select_related('some fields')                                    
logging.info(products_list)
```

And this works on my local development server, but does not on production. I see logs entered my view, but does not see logs entered `search` method of my Manager. Why that can happen?  
**UPDATE 1:**

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level = logging.INFO,
    format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
    filename = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'djjj.log'),
    )
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Localized the problem - it is in `filter(search_vector=query)` part and `search_vector` is:

```
import django.contrib.postgres.search as pg_search

search_vector = pg_search.SearchVectorField(null=True)
```

This field has a text in a database. Can it be caused by that - I have uploaded full database to the server and it somehow does not see that field?
After using shell and Pycharm debuging tool - I see the content of `serach_vector` like this:

```
'\\'active\\':7C \\'astera\\':1A,6C \\'cool\\':9C \\'minerals\\':8C \\'mint\\':10C \\'зубная\\':2A \\'минералами\\':5A \\'паста\\':3A \\'с\\':4A'
```

What are those `\\`? May be those characters are premixed some how to the words and that is the problem? When I check that field in pgAdmin - I see only letters, no any other signs. Or that is just Pycharm debugging text formatting?

Comment: I would have default manager at objects. like  
objects = models.Manager() # The default manager. and then special_products = ProductManager()

Comment: see if this is messing with the sefault queryset or something.

Comment: @Ojas Kale i have changed `objects = models.Manager()
    special_products = ProductManager()`, but that still does not help. should I make any migrations or smt?

Comment: hm. for model managers you definitely dont need to run migrations

Comment: I don't see any issue in ModelManager, instead, I doubt on the logging setting. There are multiple ways to debug these:

1. If it is possible on production server, raise an exception in search method and see if it fails.

2. Enable DB logs to see what query is being executed.

3. Instead of using logging, you can use print statement and check it in uwsgi logs.

Comment: @Mohammad Mustaqeem I have added logging settings. I have moved from print to logging - i have read it is much efficient. How can I rise an exception in search method, as you said?

Comment: @Chiefir, yes you are right, logging is efficient than print. I was just asking for debugging purpose. May I know where have you defined `logging.basicConfig`? and if possible give the full view.

Comment: How you get it is not working? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @Mohammad Mustaqeem, no, there are no any errors, just empty QuerySet is returned. I cant give a full view - it is very big and it works ok, except this part. `logging.basicConfig` is configured in the main settings.py file

Comment: Just a silly question, do you have enough data on the production server? :) You can confirm by running the same `search` statements on `shell` management command.

Comment: @Mohammad Mustaqeem I see the data exists in the database - I have another queries (without custom managers) - and they work good. Just this one does not. Can you give any advice how to debug that?

Comment: @Mohammad Mustaqeem I managed to see `logging` from my Manager, see please *Update 2*